# Wallet JSON RPC methods

Tags: monerod, rpc

I need the following JSON RPC methods.

1. create new account (`getnewaddress`)
2. get balance by address/account (`getbalance`)
3. send balance to another address (`sendfrom`)
4. import/export privatekey (`dumpprivkey`, `importprivkey`)

Those methods mentioned in brackets are like `bitcoind` JSON RPC. Could you please let me know if there are any similar JSON RPC methods for those purposes in Monero?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. create_account
2. get_balance
3. transfer_split
4. query_key and create_wallet

See https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html for basic documentation.